# configuring netem on same machine

Tags: linux, networking

I want to introduce the latency while accessing some files from my system such that I can measure the effect of latency for my application while accessing the data from the network (to be simulated using `netem` module).

I did the following to achieve this :-

I used two machines `Host1` and `Host2`, and I placed the files to be accessed by the application on `Host1` hard disk which can be accessed using `/net/<login>/Host1/data` and I launced my application on `Host2` and accessed the data from `Host1` using the path mentioned above.

I also introduced latency on `Host1` using `tc qdisc del dev eth0 root netem delay 20ms` such that whenever the files are accessed from `Host2` application, the access to data from Host1 should have a latency of 20ms.

I have couple of doubts :

1. Is there a way by which I could run the application on the same machine where the latency is set. I DONOT want the latency for the application which I will be running (Sometimes application could be accessed from another server, so If I launch the application on the machine having latency, then application would also be effected). So, is there a way I could introduce latency only to access of files.
2. Am I doing the correct usage of `tc` command for testing my scenario. So I just need conformation whether I am doing the correct usage of `tc` command.

Comment: what protocol to access Host1 disk from Host2 do you use ? NFS or a dedicated protocol from your appliacation ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, netem is intended for testing network traffic shaping, not hard disk traffic...

1. You could limit your netem rules to a specific test port on your localhost by [building a tree](http://mytestbed.net/projects/omf/wiki/NetEM_examples_of_rules). Its fairly abstruse, but possible.
2. The general scenario looks correct to me. The host that serves the resource should have `tc` running on it. The second host should be the monitor/measurer.